# Gnome Themes Not showing

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.10

I recently upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10 and now my user themes are not showing as options in gnome tweak tool.  I have user themes extension installed, but still no luck with themes.  Also, none of the themes show for the shell dropdown either.  Any guidance appreciated.

[image]

Comment: themes are installed in home directory in .themes folder.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your computer?

Comment: yes, and that had no effect.

Comment: any other thoughts?

Comment: There can be any of various things that can go wrong. Could you add a screenshot of GNOME Tweaks window?

Answer (score 1):

I also had trouble recently setting up themes in Gnome Tweak... had to do it from terminal. Maybe that can help you:

```
# Applications
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Pop'

# Icons
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Pop'

# Cursor
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'Pop'
```